# On Axiom of Choice and the principle of Explosion (ex contradictione sequitur quodlibet)

Tags: logic, set-theory, axiom-of-choice, nonclassical-logic

My question is on the relation of this two principles.

For instance, in the of Intuitionistic set theory we can prove Zorns Lemma (but Zorns Lemma will not be equivalent to the axiom of choice, since choice implies tertium non datur). Suppose now you have a paraconsistent set theory which models Zorns Lemma. It is reasonable to assume that in this case Zorns Lemma and axiom of choice are equivalent ?

Does the axiom of choice imply the principle of explosion ?

Could you recomend me some literature on this ?

Comment: In my opinion, it is not quite right to say that _tertium non datur_ (or law of the excluded middle) is provable from the Axiom of Choice, also because I guess you refer to the formulation of the Axiom of Choice in standard ZF, but standard ZF is _based on_ classical logic.

Comment: But every heyting valued model is a model of ZF right ?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco What I mean is that you can have in principle algebra-valued models of ZF whose logic is not classical. Could you explain more ?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco I think that OP refers to [Diaconescu's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaconescu%27s_theorem) (highly recommend checking that out, cool and simple proof). We can indeed derive the law of excluded middle from choice, but we also need full separation. The latter is not always accepted in intuitionistic versions of set theory.

Comment: I do not think Zorn's lemma is provable from IZF, although Zorn's lemma is consistent with IZF.

Comment: If Zorn's lemma is provable from IZF, then ZF proves Zorn's lemma too, but we know that the axiom of choice is independent of ZF.